# Ошибка при подключении к хосту с кириллицей в адресе

Tags: java

Пытаюсь сохранить картинку. Ругается на кириллические символы в адресе `http://гувм.мвд.рф/media/fms/img/logo.png`

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.URL;

public class SaveImage {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String imageUrl = "http://гувм.мвд.рф/media/fms/img/logo.png";
        String destinationFile = "d:\\image.jpg";

        saveImage(imageUrl, destinationFile);
    }

    public static void saveImage(String imageUrl, String destinationFile) throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
        InputStream is = url.openStream();
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(destinationFile);

        byte[] b = new byte[2048];
        int length;

        while ((length = is.read(b)) != -1) {
            os.write(b, 0, length);
        }

        is.close();
        os.close();
    }

}
```

Как это устранить?

Comment: кириллические домены преобразуются в punycode перед использованием, а у вас этого шага нет, я не уверен, что URL это делает автоматом.

Comment: @Etki , Оформите как ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Раньше доменое имя содержало только ASCII символы. По мере популярности интернета возникла необходимость поддержки интернационализации доменных имен, которые включают в себя символы Юникода.
Отсюда выплывает [IDN](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDN) - это доменные имена, которые содержат символы национальных алфавитов, например, президент.рф

> Чтобы можно было не менять инфраструктуру DNS, было предложено преобразовывать имена, содержащих символы национальных алфавитов, в слова, состоящие только из допустимых ранее символов ASCII, причём делать это в клиентских приложениях.
> Таким образом, для поддержки IDN достаточно, чтобы их понимал браузер/приложение пользователя. Он должен уметь переводить их в символьную кодировку **Punycode (см. ниже)**, позволяющую представить любые символы Unicode с помощью разрешённого ранее набора символов ASCII.
>
> Чтобы в таком представлении IDN нельзя было спутать с обычными доменными именами, они начинаются со специального префикса «xn--», например, «xn--abc.com»

**Punycode** - стандартизированный метод преобразования последовательностей Unicode-символов в так называемые ACE-последовательности (англ. ASCII Compatible Encoding — кодировка, совместимая с ASCII), которые состоят только из алфавитно-цифровых символов, как это разрешено в доменных именах. Punycode был разработан для однозначного преобразования доменных имен в последовательность ASCII-символов.

---

Как следствие для выполнение вашей задачи, можно прогнать `imageUrl` через дополнительный метод, который преобразует адрес, содержащий русские буквы к корректному виду.

Например:

```
public static String convertToPunycode(String stringUrl)  {
    URL url;
    try {
        url = new URL(stringUrl);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        return stringUrl;
    }

    String punycodeURL = java.net.IDN.toASCII(url.getHost());

    return url.getProtocol() + "://" + punycodeURL + url.getPath();
}
```

Тогда в методе `saveImage` надо будет написать вместо

`URL url = new URL(imageUrl);`

так

`URL url = new URL(convertToPunycode(imageUrl));`

т.е.

```
public static void saveImage(String imageUrl, String destinationFile) throws IOException {
    URL url = new URL(convertToPunycode(imageUrl));
    InputStream is = url.openStream();
    ...
    и далее по коду
```